# Random Sampling with different probabilities

Tags: python, random

I'm pretty new to python and maybe this is a very silly/stupid question, but I've got a tremendous headache from thinking about this problem.

I got a set of data, for example integers, from which I want to extract a random subset, but every object has a different probability. How can I extract the subset in a way that respect the probability distribution of the data?

I suppose that `np.random_sample` gives to all samples the same priority, so its not what I'm looking for...

Comment: If you have a recent version of Python, take a look at `random.choices`.

Comment: that's what i was looking for, thank you

Comment: For the sake of completeness, there's also scipy.stats.rv_discrete. But it's easier to use either random.choices or numpy.random.choice in your situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) has a `p` parameter that lets you set probabilities for the different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy library is usually faster, but if you wish to use python's random library

you can try:

```
random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
```

[link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)